# Бот не может найти юзера, чтобы его кикнуть

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я делаю бота, который по истечению срока подписки удалял юзера из чата.
Делаю его через `kick_chat_member`. Но бот не выгоняет юзера, хоть он есть в чате, вот текст ошибки:

> ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful.
> Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: USER_NOT_PARTICIPANT"

сам код

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
```

- юзер, которого хочу забанить в чате есть
- Тип чата - приватный
- язык - python

Comment: А вы уверены что эот юзер есть в группе? Ошибка говорит об обратном

Comment: Да, юзер есть. я для теста сделал бан после /start. юзер старт в чат пишет, но бот его не находит